# iOS Swift Charts Display X-Axis Error

Tags: swift

I am using the Charts framework found [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

My graphs look like this:

[image]

My left graph has a bunch of values under my first bar and my second graph is missing a value under my second bar. My function to set up the graph is as follows:

```
func setChart(chartview: BarChartView, xarray: [String], yarray: [Double]){

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []


        for i in 0..<xarray.count {

            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(yarray[i]))

            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")

        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        chartview.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:xarray)

        chartview.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

        chartview.chartDescription?.enabled = false

        chartview.rightAxis.enabled = false

        chartview.legend.enabled = false

        chartview.data = chartData

    }
```

I use the same functions to create other graphs and they show up fine but for some reason sometimes they show like this.

**Update:**

Below are both arrays during runtime for each graph:

Graph 1:

```
["iOS 10", "iOS 9"]
[67.0, 19.0]
```

Graph 2:

```
["2.1.0.6", "2.1.0.5", "2.0.32", "2.0.30", "2.0.23", "1.3.2.8"]
[67.0, 7.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample arrays data for the second graph?

Comment: I have provided the print out of both xarray and yarray at runtime for both graphs above.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. May be sometimes you are getting wrong data? Like `["2.1.0.6", "", "2.0.32", "2.0.30", "2.0.23", "1.3.2.8"]`

Comment: `chartview.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:xarray)` is what is setting the values so I printed out `xarray` and the array is perfectly fine. It only shows "iOS 10, iOS 9" but it prints out iOS 10 three times.

Comment: Added the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this :

```
barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
```

Comment: I think that fixed it. What does that do?

Comment: /// When true, axis labels are controlled by the `granularity` property.
    /// When false, axis values could possibly be repeated.
    /// This could happen if two adjacent axis values are rounded to same value.
    /// If using granularity this could be avoided by having fewer axis values visible.
    Default value for granularityEnabled is false

Comment: Would you happen to know how to solve the issue here: github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2751